# Calculus - $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this problem:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k-1}$$

I need to find the sum.

$$S_n=(\frac{e}{\pi})^0+(\frac{e}{\pi})^1+(\frac{e}{\pi})^2+(\frac{e}{\pi})^3+....+(\frac{e}{\pi})^{k-1}$$

I'm trying to use telescoping sum, but I don't find the $r$ value.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a geometric series. For $x$ with $|x|<1$, we have the following identity

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3\dots.$$

(Prove this, or find a proof, if you have not yet seen a justification.)

Can you see how to use this to find the sum?

Answer (score 0):

This is a geometric series   [image: geometric series]

Use the formula for partial sum:

[image: sum of series]

take the limit
[image: limit of sum of geo series]

make sure that you substitute n-1  for n

a=1

r=e/pi

-1 < r <1, so the limit will work out to a/(1-r)

and the sum should get to approx 7.422